# Skip some Value while looping

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a code which counting pages as the user set, the problem is the ListView is skipping some of the row !!
I tried the code alone as a java code and it's work well !!
Here's the code:

```
public void CollectThePages(int Num1,int Num2){
    int startpage = Num1;
    int endpage = Num2;
    int Number = startpage;
    int Day = 1;
    int DailyPages = 9;



    while(Number >= startpage){
        HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
        if(Number == startpage){
            System.out.println("Day Number " + Day);
            data.put("day", "Day " + Day);
            Day ++;
            System.out.print("From " + Number);
            data.put("from","From " + Number);
            Number += DailyPages;
            int NumberofPages = DailyPages + 1;
            System.out.print(" To "+Number);
            data.put("to", "To " + Number);
            System.out.println(" | The Pages are " + NumberofPages);
            data.put("NOP",NumberofPages + " Pages");
        }

        if(Number >= startpage){
            Number +=1;
            System.out.println("Day Number " + Day);
            data.put("day", "Day " + Day);
            Day ++;
            System.out.print("From "+Number);
            data.put("from", "From " + Number);
            Number += DailyPages;
            int NumberofPages = DailyPages + 1;
            System.out.print(" To "+Number);
            data.put("to", "To " + Number);
            System.out.println(" | The Pages are " + NumberofPages);
            data.put("NOP", NumberofPages + " Pages");
        }

        if(Number > endpage | (Number + DailyPages) > endpage){
            Number +=1;
            System.out.println("Day Number " + Day);
            data.put("day","Day " + Day);
            Day ++;
            System.out.print("From " + Number);
            data.put("from","From " + Number);
            int value = endpage - Number;
            Number += value;
            System.out.print(" To " + Number);
            data.put("to", "To " + Number);
            System.out.println(" | The Pages are " + (value + 1));
            data.put("NOP",value + " Pages");

        }

        if(Number == endpage | (Number + 1) == endpage){
            Number = 0;
        }
        valueList.add(data);
    }

    ValueList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.valueList);
    //Out of The Loop
    valueListAdapter = new ValueListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),valueList);
    ValueList.setAdapter(valueListAdapter);
}
```

And Here's the result (First page is 1, Last is 55) - Skipped the 1st day and 5th day
[image: Skipped the 1st day and 5th day !!]

Comment: why your used same logic in both if and while loop

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Num1 is 1 and Num2 is 55 (Just for trying).

Comment: @KCN that because the loop is start from Num1 to Num2, and I don't want it get more than Num2.

Comment: @AbdullahAlmuqbil Can you tell what println prints in the first condition ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna : The first condition is to put the Num1 than as it is (in From) than add DailyPages to it.
For Example, if Num1 = 1 and Num2 = 55, The First condition do that :
Day 1 | From 1 (Num1) To 10 (After adding DailyPages).

Comment: I got that, but I am saying did your println commands print all data in correct form as you wished before calling data.put method ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: yes, it is.

Comment: Instead of using two loops you can check like this if(Num1 <=Num2 ) checks from 1 to 55

Comment: @AbdullahAlmuqbil ok I got it bro... I will tell brief in answer..

Comment: @KCN : The Num1 and Num2 are Constants, and I need to condition to stop the loop, so I do it because of that.

Comment: Increment day values ,Number of pages value after             data.put("NOP",value + " Pages"); this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shree Krishna correctly pointed out your mistake and should fix your code accordingly. You can use following as well :-

```
 public void CollectThePages(int Num1,int Num2){
        int startpage = Num1;
        int endpage = Num2;
        int Number = startpage;
        int Day = 1;
        int DailyPages = 9;

        while(Number <= endpage){
            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            System.out.print("Day Number " + Day);
            data.put("day", "Day " + Day);
            ++Day;
            System.out.print("From " + Number);
            data.put("from", "From " + Number);
            int prevNumber = Number;
            Number += DailyPages;
            Number = Number > endpage ? endpage : Number;
            int NumberofPages = Number - prevNumber + 1;
            System.out.print(" To " + Number);
            data.put("to", "To " + Number);
            System.out.print(" | The Pages are " + NumberofPages);
            data.put("NOP", NumberofPages + " Pages");
            ++Number;
            valueList.add(data);
        }

        ValueList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.valueList);
        //Out of The Loop
        valueListAdapter = new ValueListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),valueList);
        ValueList.setAdapter(valueListAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Can you explain this point for me ? Because I started learning jave last month and I try to understand every think how they come .. Thank you a lot ..

Answer (score 0):

As your logic in codes, Simply lets take an example if

```
Num1 = 1
```

Your condition will be

```
if(Number == startpage) ---> if(1 == 1) //Condition satisfied
```

Then what happened is `Day` is increased by 1 and added to variable `data`.

Another condition in the same loop

```
if(Number >= startpage) ---> if(10 >= 1) //Again Condition satisfied
```

Then again `Day` is increased by 1

**Conclusion**

Your every data is being shown with +1 added.

**To prevent this**

Check your every if condition and make them all unique, Don't make it repetitive in the same condition, OR change the value of `startpage` too in each condition if it doesn't violate your logic in future.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.   
Can you explain this point for me ? Because I started learning jave last month and I try to understand every think how they come ..
Thank you a lot ..